# jmeter 3.2 debugger not working

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, blazemeter

I'm using jmeter 3.2. I'm running Debugger plugin using GUI mode.

My debugger is not working, my exception is:

```
2017-07-12 14:27:41,149 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: com.blazemeter.jmeter.debugger.gui.LoggerPanelWrapping
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.debugger.gui.DebuggerDialogBase.getLogTab(DebuggerDialogBase.java:102) ~[jmeter-debugger-0.3.jar:?]
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.debugger.gui.DebuggerDialogBase.getStatusPane(DebuggerDialogBase.java:75) ~[jmeter-debugger-0.3.jar:?]
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.debugger.gui.DebuggerDialogBase.getMainPane(DebuggerDialogBase.java:66) ~[jmeter-debugger-0.3.jar:?]
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.debugger.gui.DebuggerDialogBase.<init>(DebuggerDialogBase.java:57) ~[jmeter-debugger-0.3.jar:?]
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.debugger.gui.DebuggerDialog.<init>(DebuggerDialog.java:45) ~[jmeter-debugger-0.3.jar:?]
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.debugger.gui.DebuggerMenuItem.actionPerformed(DebuggerMenuItem.java:64) ~[jmeter-debugger-0.3.jar:?]
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_91]
```

Is there a solution to my problem?

Comment: add jmeter-plugin tag

Answer (score 0):

This plugin is for now incompatible with 3.2.

You need to wait for it to be upgraded by jmeter-plugins project.